# Acceleration due to gravity

Tags: acceleration

Why is it difficult to drink water inside the artificial satellite in the space?

I think one of the reasons is that there is no gravity in space and hence we cannot drink water. but I am not sure about this reason. So, please can anyone provide me a more scientific reason?

Comment: Astronauts have spent an entire year on the ISS without dying from thirst. They have also shot plenty of videos of how one can eat and drink in weightlessness. That there is no gravity in space is false, by the way. The gravity of Earth at the altitude of the ISS is very similar to that on the surface. The ISS and the astronauts are simply in free fall, which can be sustained indefinitely in orbit, but that, on Earth, is only possible for a few (ten) seconds before we are hitting something.

Comment: @curiousone is the question meaningless from your point of view?

Comment: We can obviously drink water in space, so I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: "inside the artificial in the space?"-- What does this mean? Is there a word missing?

Comment: @BILL,the missing word was 'satellite'

Comment: *"I think one of the reasons is that there is no gravity in space"* - If that is true, what is it that keeps the Moon orbiting the Earth, or the Earth orbiting the Sun?

Answer (score 1):

I would think that the difficulty is related to gravity. Without gravity, water will go everywhere in all directions.

Comment: There is no "without gravity" in space. The water  and the astronaut are in free fall. They are under the influence of gravity